# In CSS, can you make the background of TEXT a certain color?

Tags: css, text, colors, background

I can change the background color of a block of text, but I want it to look like the text is highlighted with a highlighter. Is it possible to only have the characters background color changed?

Comment: Can you post an example of the desired result? as it is pretty unclear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Do it with a `span` tag:

```
.highlight {
    background-color: #FFFF00;
}

<span class="highlight">Yellow text.</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

We have a tag to directly highlight some content :

```
<mark> content here </mark>
```

Or, you can use the approach as suggested by @Victor

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways to achieve this. See the method bellow.

**Method:**

1. Wrap the text you intend to select in a **span** or **strong** with position value
   of relative
2. Use **:before** or **:after** selector to create the overlay.
3. Reduce the opacity of the after or before element to create the highlight  effect

```css
#content  {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
  width: 500px;
  }

.highlighter, .one, strong  {
  position:relative;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  }

 strong:after, .highlighter:after, .one:after  {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  height: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.40;
  left: 0;
  }

 strong:after  {
  background-color: green;
  
  }

.highlighter:after  {
  background-color: red;

  }

.one:after  {
  background-color: orange;

  }
```

```html
<div id="content">



 <span class="one">bzds</span> Lorem ipsum <strong> dolor sit amet, consectetuv</strong>  sdgag r adipiscing elit. Curabitur quam augue, vehicula quis Lorem ipsum dolor <span class="highlighter">sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing</span> elit. Curabitur quam augue, vehicula quis
  sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Curabitur quam augue, vehicula quis



</div>
```